# Method not allowed, flask, python

Tags: python, docker, flask

Installed FlareSolverr in docker.

cURL work correctly and return the correct response.

```
curl -L -X POST 'http://localhost:8191/v1' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{
  "cmd": "request.get",
  "url":"http://google.com",
  "maxTimeout": 60000
}'
```

but when using from python + flask I get an error - 405 Method is not allowed

```
def get_parsed_page(url, delay=0.5):
data = {
    "cmd": "request.get",
    "url": url,
    "maxTimeout": 60000
}
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
time.sleep(delay)
print(requests.get("***:8191/v1", headers=headers, data=data))
return BeautifulSoup(requests.get("***:8191/v1", headers=headers, data=data).text, 'lxml')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using a GET request in your python code. It should be a POST request. Use `requests.post`

Comment: Why can't I use a GET request?

Comment: Because you're sending data in the body of the request.

Comment: FlareSolverr designed their API to only accept a POST request. You can see in your curl command that you are using a POST request and that is why it worked there. As mentioned by @PGHE, when sending data in the body, you have to use POST or some other ones like PUT and so on. GET does not accept body data.